# how to define default selected value in select form page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I  have an index.rhtml with this code

```
<select id="subtable" name="subtable" size="20" style="width: 400px">
      <% for haus in @hauses %> 
           <option selected value="<%= haus.id %>"><%= haus.timebuild%></option>
       <% end %>
</select>
```

It will show me a list of drop down files in a select box. However, everytime I refresh the page, the default selected value is always the last of the list (the bottom one). How can I make the default selected value to be the 1st one (the top one of the list), and not the last one?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `selected` attribute is supposed to be placed on only the default-selected value, but you're putting it on all values, causing the last one to remain selected.

The simplest solution is just remove the `selected` attribute altogether.

You should probably use Rails view helpers, which handles this for you (and doing things like automatically default to the current attribute's value):

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@hauses, 'id', 'timebuild', @hauses.first.id)
```

Comment: I tried the code, but it eventually ended up creating a blank select table. If I use the for loop, it renders correctly, but the problem is just the default selection. So is it not possible to add other parameter in the <option selected value> that points to the 1st field?

Comment: AHA! now I know what's wrong.. it should be with <%= > and not <option> </option>

Comment: This doesn't work for me! I don't know if they've changed the syntax or what but the 4th attribute `@hauses.first.id` does not work. Whatever I put in there, absolutely nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: @imjp, you should ask your question as a new SO question rather than in a comment of an old answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select). Replace the `for` loop with this:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@hauses, 'id', 'timebuild', @hauses.first.id)
```

Comment: So in index.rhtml , I wrote this <options_from_collection_for_select(@hauses, 'id', 'timebuild', @hauses.first.id)> </option> , however seems that I have to use the for loop. Because when I tried your code, the list of files in the select table just vanish (without no error)