# How do I set the default selected item in a Rails drop-down menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When creating a standard Rails dropdown menu how do you set which item in the list should be default?
I ask because in the past I've been just putting a nil entry as the first item in my list of values that are going into the drop-down, but when using {:include_blank => true} the blank entry is not the default selected item, the first item from the list is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to define default selected value in select form page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967883/how-to-define-default-selected-value-in-select-form-page)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use :selected

```
<%= f.select :title, ['1','2','3','4'], :selected => '3' %>
```

Comment: Both answers were good but this one was closest to what I needed for my implementation. Thanks!

Comment: `%td= select_tag user.name, ['approved','not approved'], selected: 'approved'`

Comment: @TamerShlash `%td= select_tag user.name, options_for_select(['approved','not approved'], 'approved')`

Comment: @TamerShlash, `select_tag` has different API then `select` http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Comment: @fl00r thanks - is there any way of selecting the blank response from the drop down menu as a default?

Answer (score 10):

You have many options to populate `<select>` tag with `<option>` tags, one of them is [options_for_select(container, selected = nil)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)  which takes a selected param which should be the value of your `<option>` field you want to be selected by default.