# Simple form default value in select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using simple form, and I have the :selected => 0 so that the select has value 0 from its collection by default. But this is not working, the select box is blank and I need to choose the "0" option manually... I'm in a modal by the way. Any idea?

```
  <%= f.input :price_type, label: "¿Conoces el precio?", collection: ["0","1","2"], :selected => 0 , id: "tag_price_type", html_input: "required", input_html: {class: 'ipt'} %>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the output source code? The 0 option should look something like <option value="0" selected>0</option>. If that's the case this could be a browser issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try matching the object types between the collection and the selection. So either:

```
<%= f.input :price_type, label: "¿Conoces el precio?", collection: [0,1,2], selected: 0 , id: "tag_price_type", html_input: "required", input_html: {class: 'ipt'} %>
```

or

```
<%= f.input :price_type, label: "¿Conoces el precio?", collection: ['0','1','2'], selected: '0' , id: "tag_price_type", html_input: "required", input_html: {class: 'ipt'} %>
```

Comment: it wont work, thats why Im so confused. I'm inside a modal, could that be the cause? Doesnt make any sense!

Comment: If it is a multiple selected, how could I :selected => [1, 2, 3] ? It seems not work.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use quotes, see: [How do I set the default selected item in a Rails drop-down menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880038/how-do-i-set-the-default-selected-item-in-a-rails-drop-down-menu)

So you should have: :selected => "0"